# Bulk insert to SQL Server with linq

Tags: sql-server, linq

I read the xml file with linq and create list of objects.

```
 StringReader stream=new StringReader(xml);
 XmlTextReader reader=new XmlTextReader(stream);

XElement req = XElement.Load(reader);
var users= (req.Descendants("Report")
           .Select(e => new { 
            Fname= e.Descendants("firstName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            Lname = e.Descendants("lastName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            personalId = e.Descendants("id").FirstOrDefault().Value,
            })).ToList();
```

the users value include 100,000 objects.

I want bulk insert these objects into a database table.

Comment: That's a good idea. If you have problems, feel free to come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Bulk insert is not possible in LINQ, you should send the XML via stored procedure and parse it in the SP. Otherwise, InsertOnSubmit will eat up lots of time because for every single row, each call will be made to SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void saveData<T>(ref List<T> list, string destinationTableName, int batchSize)
{
    using (EntityDataReader<T> reader = new EntityDataReader<T>(list))
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy sbc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy("your connection string"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            string colName = reader.GetName(i);
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(colName, colName);
        }
        sbc.BatchSize = batchSize;
        sbc.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
        sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

I'm using this code to insert a very large list of items, T should be a known entity object